# tiny javascript closure question

Tags: javascript, closures

```
for(var i=0,len=btns.length;i<len;i++){
    (function(){
     btns[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
        console.log(i)
         },false)
    })(i)}}
```

Hello everyone, I'm recently learning Javascript. In the above code for understanding a bit of closure, you know, just set 3 buttons to log 3 different `i`.

Unfortunately, it failed. I know that I didn't get the point of closures. Why? I immediately execute the function so that the `i` in the listener's callback function won't share the same `i`

Hope someone can help~

Comment: It would e much easier for us to help if you posted a link to a jsFiddle demonstrating your problem

Comment: @Grezzo,Thanks for your advice,Next Time I'll do so

Answer (score 4):

You pass the `i` variable to the function, but the function ignores the argument and just binds to the `i` inside the function is the same variable as the one outside (because you specify an empty formal parameter list).

Therefore your loop has completed and increased the single `i` shared between all the closures to `3` before you get a chance to push any of the buttons.

Rewrite `function()` with `function(i)` and it will have a better chance of working.

Comment: Oh...I see,I wana to kill myself immediately,Such a foolish post,next Time I'll scan it carefully before post my questions,Thank @Henning Makholm

Answer (score 1):

Try this where you actually declare a parameter for the function so that `i` gets a local definition inside the function:

```
for(var i = 0, len = btns.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(i){
        btns[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            console.log(i);
        },false);
    })(i);
}
```

As you had it, you were passing `i` as a parameter to the function, but not actually defining it as a parameter so the passed one was not being used.  This is one reason why it's a bad idea to use the same name because these types of mistakes won't make a javascript error.  I'd prefer this with a different name for the internal variable so there's no chance of confusion between the two:

```
for(var i = 0, len = btns.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(loopVar){
        btns[loopVar].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            console.log(loopVar);
        },false);
    })(i);
}
```

You can see this work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Hb5t3/

Comment: Did you mean btns[i] or btns[loopVar] in your last example?